# How to to get OnEdit to work if you paste/duplicate multiple lines at once in Google app script / sheets?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a Google app script that does a lookup when a value is entered into column 20(T). My problem is that the script doesn't work if I copy and paste in multiple lines of values into column 20(T). How would I tweak my script so that it would work with multiple lines of Copy and Paste?

```
function onEdit(e){
let ss = SpreadsheetApp
let activeSheet = ss.getActive().getActiveSheet()
let lookupSheet = ss.getActive().getSheetByName("Workbook")
let editedCell = e.range
let editedCol = editedCell.getColumn()
let editedRow = editedCell.getRow()
let lookupReferences = lookupSheet.getRange("A3:A").getValues().map((elem)=>elem[0].toUpperCase().trim())
let lookupValues = lookupSheet.getRange("C3:C").getValues()
let rowFound;
if (e.value !== "" && e.value !==null && e.value !== undefined && editedCol==20){
  for (let [index,reference] of lookupReferences.entries()){
  if (e.value.toUpperCase().trim() == reference)
  rowFound = index
  }
activeSheet.getRange(editedRow,editedCol+2,1,1).setValue(lookupValues[rowFound])
}
else if((e.value == "" || e.value == null) &&editedCol ==20){
  activeSheet.getRange(editedRow,editedCol+2,1,1).setValue("")
}
}
```

I don't have the sheet because of private data, but I can make an example copy if anyone needs it to help. All the script does is a lookup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### You can refer to this sample modification:

```
function onEdit(e){
  let lookupSheet = e.source.getSheetByName("Workbook");
  let editedCell = e.range;
  let editedCol = editedCell.getColumn();
  let editedRow = editedCell.getRow();
  let totalRow = editedCell.getNumRows();
  let totalCol = editedCell.getNumColumns();
  let lookupReferences = lookupSheet.getRange("A3:A").getValues().map((elem)=>elem[0].toUpperCase().trim())
  let lookupValues = lookupSheet.getRange("C3:C").getValues()
  let rowFound;
  
  Logger.log("totRow: "+totalRow+" totCol: "+totalCol+" startRow: "+editedRow+" startCol: "+editedCol);
  if(totalCol==1 && editedCol==20){
    //Loop all rows
    for(var i = 0; i<totalRow; i++){
      var currentRow = editedCell.offset(i,0);
      var value = currentRow.getValue();
      Logger.log("curr row: "+currentRow.getRow()+" value: "+value);
      if(value !== "" && value !==null && value !== undefined){
        for (let [index,reference] of lookupReferences.entries()){
          if (value.toUpperCase().trim() == reference){
            rowFound = index
            break;
          }
        }
        lookupSheet.getRange(currentRow.getRow(),editedCol+2,1,1).setValue(lookupValues[rowFound])

      }
      else if(value == "" || value == null){
        lookupSheet.getRange(currentRow.getRow(),editedCol+2,1,1).setValue("")
      }
    }
  }

}
```

### What it does?

1. Get total number of rows and column and the start row and column of the modified range.
2. Check if modified cells were under a single column and if it is in column 20.
3. Loop each rows based on the total number of rows and get the current row range using [Range.offset(rowOffset, columnOffset)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#offsetrowoffset,-columnoffset)
4. Get the value and the row number of the current row obtained in step 3
5. Apply your old procedure in checking for a lookup value. (I added a break in the loop when a matching index was found, you can remove that if you find it unecessary)

**Note:**

> Since this is just a sample reproduction, I only used a single sheet to get the lookup values and display the value.

### Output:

[image]